# Переход на другую страницу при помощи функции

Tags: javascript, html, html5, href, location

Есть кнопка c событием onclick

```
 <button onclick = 'fn()' >click</button>
```

внутри функции перенаправление window.location на какую-либо html страницу

таких кнопок нужно много, и для каждой страницы я написал отдельную функцию.

но как написать одну, которая параметром бы принимала название страницы, добавляла .html и обрабатывала все это для перехода на эту страницу?

вот пример того что придумал, но не работает

```
function changeDay(day){
  window.location.href = `${day}.html`
}
```

нужна ли здесь вообще шаблонная строка?

Comment: Шаблонная строка не нужна `day + '.html'`

Comment: onclick="changeDay(monday)"      function changeDay(day){
   window.location.href = day + '.html'
}   название файла monday.html           не работает

Comment: Ты не так написал... Для получения итоговой строки `monday.html` нужно писать `onclick="changeDay('monday')"`. Т.е. передавать таки строку, а не значение (наверное не существующей) переменной...

Comment: точно, спасибо большое

Comment: Если бы сделал полный тестовый пример - получил бы сразу исчерпывающий ответ. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложу тебе альтернативный вариант для такого рода кнопок...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-url]').forEach(o => {
  o.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const url = e.target.dataset.url + '.html'
    alert('Переход будет по ' + url)
    //window.location = url
  })
})
```

```html
<button data-url='УРЛ1'>click 1</button>
<button data-url='УРЛ2'>click 2</button>
<button data-url='УРЛ3'>click 3</button>
```

Comment: большое спасибо, сохранил, будет полезно в будущем